# Spring Boot Hikari can't find DriverClassName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project,It run just fine when I execute via eclipse `Project > Run as > spring boot app`

but when I build the project and execute it using `java -jar myproject.jar` or run it using `mvn spring-boot:run` it throw this error

```
Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

Property: driverclassname
Value: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
.SQLServerDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

my sql server connector dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and here my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mydb;databaseName=HTSdb
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

it looks my app can't find the sqlserver driver but it is already in project classpath,any suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the issue is with dependency scope which is set as **test**.

Scope **test** indicates that dependency isn't required at standard runtime of application and should only be used for purpose of test runs only!

Usually database connectors dependency are set with **runtime** scope.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

Property: driver-class-name
Value: org.postgresql.Driver 
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver  in either of HikariConfig 
class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Just had the same error, in my case with "org.postgresql.Driver".
Gues what was the issue? an empty space after "org.postgresql.Driver " by mistake.

So, be aware about that ' ' invisible empty space :).

Comment: work like a charm , was looking many other configurations, yup space was there

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

check if Jar is loaded in lib if not then you need to add version             8.2.1.jre8 and rebuild the project .
You can validate by checking if mssql-jdbc-8.2.1.jre8 jar is there loaded in project and it has SQLServerDriver.class file in it .